# How to use presql to delete records based on currently processed file name(Informatica)?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, flat-file

I am using Indirect file load in Informatica where source file can be one or multiple .csv files.

Source file name format is: production_plan_YYYYMMDD.csv

Target table has a column named production_date, I need to write a pre sql command which will delete all records where production_date will be matched with the date mentioned (YYYYMMDD)currently processed file name.

I can add currently processed file name port in Source but not sure if I can use this information in presql to delete records as per my logic

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to create a separate pipeline which will delete all existing data. Then your actual pipeline will start to load data.

1. read files using same list file. add a port with filename.
2. use exp transformation to make sure you have a column on which you can delete.

```
o_dt_col = substr(replacechr(file_name,'.csv',''),-8)
```

3. Create a new informatica target by copying original target and set dt_col as key.
4. Use a sorter to get distinct o_dt_col.
5. add a update strategy and set property as `DD_DELETE`. Add the new target to this.
6. Set this pipeline to run first in target load order.

```
SQ --> EXP --> SRT -->UPD --> TGT
<<original pipeline>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate mapping that will use your input file as direct input and for each file name in the input list will run a delete statement via `SQL Transformation`. Add `Filter Transformation` right after, set the condition to `FALSE` to prevent any rows from reaching the Target. Add a dummy Target to complete the flow.

```
SQ --> EXP --> SQL --> FLT --> TGT
```

Create a session for this mapping prior to the one loading the data.